# C++ template code resulting in error with delete being called on an object that apparently wasn't properly allocated

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am teaching myself c++ templates. I wrote the following code, and I am getting a weird error about a pointer being freed that wasn't allocated. I am guessing that something in my class template constructor isn't actually calling `new` on the `int` when I ask for an `<int>` type of this class. The code is being compiled and run automatically by `CodeRunner` for mac which I set up to use the `clang++` compiler for `c++` files.

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class HeapVal
{
    public:
        HeapVal(T val) {ptr = new T(val);}
        ~HeapVal() {delete ptr;}
        T get() {return *ptr;}
    private:
        T* ptr;
};

int main(){
  std::vector< ::HeapVal<int> > vec;
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    ::HeapVal<int> h(i);
    vec.push_back(h);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
    std::cout << vec[i].get() << std::endl;
  }
  return( 0 );
}
```

That code results in the following error either during compilation or execution (looks to me like a run-time kind of error).

```
Untitled(30214) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f82f24007c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Run Command: line 1: 30214 Abort trap: 6           ./"$2" "${@:3}"
```

Comment: This might explain your problem well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a copy constructor and assignment operator for `HeapVal`. The implication of that is that you'll ultimately end up trying to `delete` the same memory more than once, because you have multiple pointers to it - that's what causes the crash.

Try something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class HeapVal
{
public:
    explicit HeapVal(T val)
    :   ptr(new T(val))
    {}

    ~HeapVal()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }

    HeapVal(const HeapVal& rhs)
    :   ptr(new T(*rhs.ptr))
    {}

    HeapVal& operator=(const HeapVal& rhs)
    {
        HeapVal(rhs).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    T get() const
    {
        return *ptr;
    }

private:
    T* ptr;

    void swap(HeapVal& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(ptr, rhs.ptr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Oooh yea, the default copy constructor would just make one pointer equal to the other... I guess I didn't realize that copies would be made when I pushed something into the std::vector.

Comment: @JohnSt.John: When you pass an object to `std::vector.push_back`, the `std::vector` will copy that object into it's buffer. If it needs to resize teh buffer, then it makes copies of all items from the old buffer to the new bigger buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime a `HeapVal` is copied (or assigned, for that matter) you'll end up with two `HeapVal` objects, both containing pointers to the same place. When the first of those is destroyed, it'll delete the pointed-to object. When the second is destroyed, it'll try to delete the same object again -- leading to undefined behavior.

In your case, you were fortunate enough that the run-time library detected and reported the problem.

Googling for "C++ law of the big three" or something similar should yield quite a bit of discussion on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when u push the HeapVal object you end up doing a shallow copy of the ptr so this is prone to double delete.

You need to override the default copy constructor and assignment operator or you could use smart pointers instead of raw ptr . [Boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) maybe an overkill in your case but its something good to learn.